# jQuery $.closest() (Or whichever comes first)

Tags: jquery, closest, dom-traversal

While working a project tonight, I ended up using one .js resource file for two different pages. One page contains a textarea within a div, and another contains a textarea within a td. Wanting to work with the siblings of this textarea, and other children of its parent, I wondered how you could best implement "closest div or td, whichever comes first" logic via jQuery syntax.

What are your guys' suggestions?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$.closest("td, div")
```

?

Comment: So simple I should be ashamed ;) For some reason I failed to consider that $.closest() takes a regular selector like everything else.

Comment: Did it work? I wasn't sure it would. If it does, it'd be good to know cos I could see it being useful.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to what cletus mentioned, what is wrong with simply:

```
$("#textareaId").parent()
```

Comment: I may not want the first parent in all cases.

Comment: I don't disagree, but it suited your description.

Comment: Note "textarea within a div" != "textarea immediately within a div" :) I could have been more clear though.